# Copy X11 settings between users

Tags: fedora, x11

I am using X11 with Fedora 35 with KDE.  I spent an hour customizing my multiple screens, resolutions, etc. and it works great - all setup under USER1.  And they are saved between logins

Now if I login as USER2 all display settings appear lost.  Is there a way to transfer these settings between users?

Comment: Is there a file ~USER1/xorg.conf?

Comment: No - just the one in /etc/X11. I'm wondering if KDE applies/stores its own settings on top?

Comment: @TSG can you see if there's any content inside of `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml`? You can check by doing `cat ~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Comment: No such file (check all users)